# How to implement Single Choice select in Wicket Select2 compoment

Tags: java, jquery-select2, wicket

I have wicket select2 component. I need to implement ChoiceProvider, but I dont know how to implement it. Do someone know how to do properly? Thanks for help.

I use

```
Select2Choice select2Choice = new Select2Choice("select2");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please consult with the Wicketstuff Select2 [examples](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/blob/master/select2-parent/select2-examples/src/main/java/org/wicketstuff/select2/HomePage.java)

A possible implementation could be:

```
public class TagProvider extends StringTextChoiceProvider
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void query(String term, int page, Response<String> response)
    {
        List<Country> matches = queryMatches(term, page, PAGE_SIZE);
        for (Country match : matches)
        {
            response.add(match.getDisplayName());
        }
        response.setHasMore(response.size() == PAGE_SIZE);
    }
}
```

and then use it:

```
Select2Choice<String> tags = new Select2Choice<>("tagsSelect",
            new PropertyModel<>(this, "tags"), new TagProvider());
```

Comment: Do you know please, how to listen changes on Select2?

Comment: And How to set values to select2 component?

Comment: `response.add(match.getDisplayName());` adds the possible choices